# QFileSystemModel and QFileSystemWatcher delete from disk

Tags: qt, qfilesystemmodel

I have a QTreeView which is populated through a reimplementation of QFileSystemModel. As far as I know, QFileSystemModel installs a QFileSystemWatcher on the rootPath. What I'm trying to do is notify in my program when a file is being deleted directicly on the rootPath but i havent found any signal o reimplemented function which provides me that information.

My application upload some files thrugh an ftp connection and when the file is fully uploaded i remove it from the location, so i want a notification from the reimplementation of QFileSystemModel when the file is deleted directicly (not from the remove method or something similar).

I Hope you can help me. I have searched a lot on the web but I cant find anything.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `FileSystemModel`'s [`rowsAboutToBeRemoved`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsAboutToBeRemoved) signal (inherited from [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemmodel.html)).

It will be fired whenever a row is removed from the model. The `parent`, `start` and `end` parameters allow you to get to the filename (in column 0 of the children).

Sample code:

```
// once you have your model set up:
...
QObject::connect(model, SIGNAL(rowsAboutToBeRemoved(const QModelIndex&, int, int)),
         receiver, SLOT(toBeRemoved(const QModelIndex&, int, int)));
...
```

```
// in receiver class:
public slots:
 void toBeRemoved(const QModelIndex &parent, int start, int end) {
  std::cout << start << " -> " << end << std::endl;
  std::cout << parent.child(start, 0).data().typeName() << std::endl;
  std::cout << qPrintable(parent.child(start, 0).data().toString()) << std::endl;
 }
```

(Using std::cout isn't good practice with Qt I think, this is just to get you started.)

The other `aboutToBe...` signals from QAbstractItemModel can be used for the other events that happen on the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks it worked!. I readed about that function on the reference but there are a few signals that are not suggested (including this) by the Qt Creator IDE (i dont know why) so that's why I didnt tried it before. Thanks again.